# Create Unix Time Stamp of next day at 10am

Tags: php

Hi Suppose I have a timestamp of "2005-10-16 13:05:41".

How would I go about creating a variable that will have a unixtime of the next time it becomes 10am from that initial point?

Would it be something like this?

```
$timestamp = "2005-10-16 13:05:41";
$tenAMTime = strtotime("next 10am", $timestamp);
```

I am guessing there is some string I can use to do this? Like "next thursday" example in the PHP documentation.

Comment: Just an another option, could you not just advance this time by one day, then set the time to 10 AM if the time is less than 10 AM, or just set it to 10 AM on the same day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for `strtotime` to know whether or not 10am has already passed, so this is how I would do it:

```
$timestamp = strtotime("2005-10-16 13:05:41");
// Get current hour and if it is > 10 add a day
if (date('G',$timestamp) >= 10) {
    $tenAMTime = strtotime("+1 day 10am", $timestamp);
}
else {
    $tenAMTime = strtotime("10am", $timestamp);
}
echo date('r',$tenAMTime); // Comment this out if you want
```

Answer (score 6):

You nearly had it...

```
$tomorrowAt10Am = strtotime('+1 day 10:00:00', $timestamp);
```

Edit:
This was based on the title of your question, for the timestamp of 10am the **next day**. If you want to output 10am the same day for any times before 10am then you'll want to add some extra logic, as thatidiotguy suggested.

**Edit2:**

For some reason it won't work if you put all the logic in the same strtotime method, so I made a simple function. You could easily put this into a single line, but I left it as 2 to make it clearer:

```
$time1 = strtotime('-2 days 09:59:59');
$time2 = strtotime('-2 days 10:00:01');

function next_10am($time)
{
    $temp = strtotime('+1 day -10 hours', $time);
    return strtotime('10:00', $temp);
}

echo next_10am($time1); // Outputs: 2012-09-08 10:00:00
echo next_10am($time2); // Outputs: 2012-09-09 10:00:00
```

Comment: What happens if it is prior to 10am on that day?

Comment: Thanks and like trickyzter mentioned what happens if one of the timestamps ends up being 9am of that same day for example. "+1 day 10:00:00" would move it up 24 hours correct?